# How can I get Istanbul's coverage.json object programmatically?

Tags: code-coverage, istanbul

I've been through each of the classes in the [Istanbul API](http://gotwarlost.github.io/istanbul/public/apidocs/) but have been unable to find out how to produce a "coverage object."

Instrumenting code is no problem at all:

```
const istanbul = require('istanbul');
const instrumenter = new istanbul.Instrumenter();
instrumenter.instrument(sourceCode, filename, (err, instrumentedCode) => {
  console.log(instrumentedCode);
}
```

But this is only the instrumented code; I need to execute it in order to produce the **coverage object**. But I cannot find out how to do this. Of course I could shell out to istanbul and run

```
istanbul cover filename.js
```

and dig up and parse the `coverage.json` file, but I *don't* want to shell out; I want to run coverage on a JavaScript program which is in memory.

So many methods in the Istanbul API, like those in `Collector` and `Reporter` allow you to process coverage objects, but they assume the coverage objects already exist. My question is how to produce coverage objects in the first place. I'm sure I am missing something simple. I noticed that `Instrumenter.lastFileCoverage()` exists; I tried that, and as advertised, got the zero coverage object including lines like this:

```
  statementMap: 
   { '1': SourceLocation { start: [Object], end: [Object], skip: undefined },
     '2': SourceLocation { start: [Object], end: [Object], skip: undefined },
```

My question is, how can I produce a *coverage object*, in memory (without shelling out)? Am I missing a simple `cover` method?

Comment: I found out _after_ posting this question that it was a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/39302198/831878. I deleted my answer here and answered the other question.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`istanbul-lib-instrument`](https://github.com/istanbuljs/istanbuljs/blob/master/packages/istanbul-lib-instrument) package from the offical istanbul api repo.

It has a method [`lastFileCoverage`](https://github.com/istanbuljs/istanbuljs/blob/master/packages/istanbul-lib-instrument/src/instrumenter.js) which differs from the standard [istanbul instrumenter's](https://github.com/gotwarlost/istanbul/blob/master/lib/instrumenter.js) implementation.

I just tested on a project I'm working on and from my experience it was a drop-in replacement (the api's instrumenter).  I also tried the `lastFileCoverage` method and it does in fact provide full file coverage for the last file processed.